# Is there a DRY way to pass bind variables to an AR Relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, active-relation

I have code like this:

```
t = "%#{term}%"
where('name like ? or email like ? or postcode like ?', t, t, t)
```

As you can see it's performing a search across several fields.

Is there a way to avoid the duplicated t? It's making me feel dirty.

Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can do it with a named placeholder:

```
where('name LIKE :name OR email LIKE :name OR postcode LIKE :name', :name => t)
```

This is often the best way to repeat a singular value several times in a query.

Answer (score 1):

```
t = "%#{term}%"
where('name || email || postcode like ?', t)
```

Comment: it's syntactically correct (|| is the string concatenation operator) but it doesn't do the same thing as the original query